# Uploade image is corrupted on server

Tags: java, android, image, ftp

Hi I am trying to upload image to server using ftp4j. My image is uploaded on server but getting corrupted. I know something is missing in my code.My code is

```
private class UploadBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(xxx.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {



        try{
            TrustManager[] trustManager = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            } };

            SSLContext sslContext = null;
            try {
                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(null, trustManager, new SecureRandom());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

            client.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            client.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES);

            client.connect("xxx.xxx.com");
            client.login("xxx", "xxx");

            client.changeDirectory("product_images/import");
            client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
            //@TODO read file from android system
            System.out.println("temPath -->"+picturepath);
            client.upload(new File(picturepath));


            FTPFile[] list = client.list();
            for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                System.out.println("-->"+list[i]);
            }


            Log.v("SUCCESFULLY UPLOADED", "SUCCESFULLY UPLOADED");
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String list) {
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

My image on server is:
[image]

My logTrace is:

```
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException [code=450, message= Transfer aborted. Link to file server lost]
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.upload(FTPClient.java:2799)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.upload(FTPClient.java:2586)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.upload(FTPClient.java:2495)
at com.Activity.xxx.AddProducts$UploadBackgroundTask.doInBackground(AddProducts.java:902)
at com.Activity.xxx.AddProducts$UploadBackgroundTask.doInBackground(AddProducts.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of:
com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41174c80
```

File size is on server is always 4 KB after uploading.why?

I searched a lot but not getting answer.
Please tell me what is wrong in my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked file sizes? That could give a hint.

Comment: On mobile image size is 27 kb but at server side it is only 4.0 KB

Comment: Is something missing in my code

Comment: Your code looks ok, the usual suspect is the binary/ascii conversion but you have it checked. The fact that the resulting file has 4k (4096 bytes), a common measure for buffer or disk sectors points to a failure elsewhere (ftp library?)

Comment: What the logs say (of the FTP Server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to implement listener like this:

```
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferListener;

public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {

    public void started() {
        // Transfer started
    }

    public void transferred(int length) {
        // Yet other length bytes has been transferred since the last time this
        // method was called
    }

    public void completed() {
        // Transfer completed
    }

    public void aborted() {
        // Transfer aborted
    }

    public void failed() {
        // Transfer failed
    }

}
```

and upload file with `client.upload(new File(picturepath), new MyTransferListener());` So you can track out what happens on file upload.

EDIT:

1. Check upladed image size and  params in method `transferred(int length)` is equals. (in case image less than 64k)
2. Check the same byte amount was received on FTP server ( check logs on FTP server)
3. If one of conditions above is not true, problem in ftp4j, if both of them true, problem in your FTP server.

Comment: It is only gets started and then only little size is shown in transferred. After that i am getting above exception.So how i can fix it?

Comment: @Rash post full exception stacktrace. There are many places where FTPException can occurs.

Comment: also check you don't restore uploading to server (that can be if you upload file with the same name)

Comment: No i am saving with differnt with names.Because i have attached timestamp to image name

Comment: @Rash what version of ftp4j you're using?

Comment: Looks like code in ftp4j is broken. They do `inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);` but on Android it maybe should be `inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));` file FTPClient.java, line 2581

Comment: i am using above jar. so how i can access FTPClient.java

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftp4j/files/ftp4j/1.7.2/ Also check ftp server logs. Maybe issue related not to reading file, but to transfer or writing file on ftp server.

Comment: and what exactly length you get in `MyTransferListener.transferred(int length)`? It's important.

Comment: Image Length is always getting different  and on server it always displayed in size 4 KB..why?

Comment: just to be clear: you upload always one image, but with different names, ok? Check size of original image and compare it with MyTransferListener.transferred(). If lengths different, then problem in reading your file from filesystem.